# Check each value have already exceeded the limit in PostgreSQL with trigger and rise a notice

Tags: function, postgresql, triggers

What I want here is to get which subject has already 4 classrooms, if it exceeds raise a notice and return null, and works. But when I insert other subject "2" the code raise the same notice, but I this subject has only 1 classrom. I know I'm using "`HAVING COUNT(cod_classroom) = 4`" and the code only get what the subject has already 4 classrooms. I tried to use this only: "`SELECT DISTINCT cod_subject,COUNT(cod_classroom) AS CountOf FROM registration_subject GROUP BY cod_subject`" But I dont know how to check more values.

I hope you all understand what I want, I tried my best =) Thank you all in advance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quantas()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$declare qtd record;

    begin

    SELECT * INTO qtd FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cod_subject,COUNT(cod_classroom) AS CountOf FROM registration_subject 
    GROUP BY cod_subject HAVING COUNT(cod_classroom) = 4) AS total;

    if found then

    raise notice 'This subject has already 4 classroom';

    return null;

    end if;

    end;$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION qtd()
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Without adding appropriate `LOCK` statements this function is prone to race conditions that means it'll incorrectly reject legitimate changes in the face of a concurrent delete and will incorrectly permit multiple inserts. You *must* lock the `registration_subject` table `IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` to get reliable results. Taking `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` row locks are not enough to protect against concurrent inserts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue Craig mentions in his comment (the need to lock IN EXCLUSIVE MODE), I think you have a couple of other problems.

Your query is this and it doesn't make much sense to me.

```
  SELECT * INTO qtd 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cod_subject,COUNT(cod_classroom) AS CountOf 
           FROM registration_subject 
GROUP BY cod_subject HAVING COUNT(cod_classroom) = 4) AS total;
```

I am not convinced this is a very helpful way to do this query.  Indeed it rather helpfully declines all inserts once any subject at all has 4 classrooms.

I would recommend instead:

```
    PERFORM count(cod_classroom)
       FROM registration_subject
      WHERE cod_subject = NEW.subject
     HAVING count(*) >= 4;
```

`PERFORM` is used in plpgsql when you don't care about using the result.  Here you only care if it is found or not.  Secondly, in the event where something goes wrong and a stray insert is allowed, you will still block subsequent inserts.  Your old code will block inserts to all subjects if *any* subject has exactly four classrooms, but 5 classrooms is ok, which is not what you want either.